# Postgres like filter indexing & perfomances with %wildcard%

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a scenario that I have to do full text search on database, based on parameters that are provided. 
So let's say if *first_name* provided I'm only doing query:

```
where(unaccent(first_name) ilike %{params[:first_name]}%
```

if *last_name* provided only this one:

```
where(unaccent(last_name) ilike %{params[:last_name]}%
```

And if both provided then I'm doing:

```
where(unaccent(first_name) ilike %{params[:first_name]}% AND 
where(unaccent(last_name) ilike %{params[:last_name]}%
```

**Note there is 3 more fields like this.**

I know I can add `GIN` indexes for each of those fields and use it pretty fast, but it would definitely increase storage space and slow down other operations, so I'm not so big fan of it.

Is there any advice how to make it faster and quite optimized but to not slow down other parts.

Comment: Did you consider a trigram index? http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: yes I did, but it doesn't allow left anchors. 
Unlike Btree-based LIKE optimization, this works for non-left-anchored
search patterns. 
Or I missed smthg?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and it uses `gin` index also, so in my case it would really slow down INSERT/UPDATE for sure

Comment: Did you measure the slowdown for your use case and found it to be unacceptable? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: Hmm I'm just guessing based on theory :) You're right. I will do first then will come back here!